# GregorianCalendar.getTime() default time is different when date is day light saving day

Tags: java, java-6

I have a very strange issue. I am not able to consistently recreate but its happening. So when the date is 04/25/1948,  GregorianCalendar.getTime() returns Date as

```
Sun Apr 25 1:00:00 EDT 1948
```

I am not sure why it has time of 1:00:00 and not 00:00:00. I am not setting any time in date.
Do you guys have any pointers of why it would set time of 1:00:00.

note: I am in EST time zone.

Thanks!

Comment: Is that your time zone offset from UTC, i.e., are you in central Europe?

Comment: I am in US EST time zone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Sun Apr 25 1:00:00 EDT 1948`, EDT indicates it is Eastern Daylight Time and currently your machine is on EST. Hence, you are seeing a difference of 1 hour.

On April 25 1948, Daylight savings was activated and EST transitioned to EDT.

For eg. check [this](https://www.horlogeparlante.com/history.html?city=4990729) to see history of daylight savings changes of Detroit.